# Mongo C# driver - find most recent date

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a collection of the below (various members omitted for brevity)

```
public class Payslip {

  public int EmployeeID { get;set; }
  public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Using the Mongo C# official driver I need to find the most recent `Payslip` for a given employee, or more specifically just the most recent date.

Is there any reason why I wouldn't want to do this with a linq query?

```
payrollItemCollection.AsQueryable().Where(p=>p.EmployeeID==input.EmployeeID).Max(p=>(DateTime?)p.Date);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no reason not to do that.
You can see on the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver/) that the MongoDB C# driver supports LINQ's `Max` method and translates it into the relevant mongo query. It's basically equivalent to:

```
payrollItemCollection.AsQueryable().Where(p=>p.EmployeeID == input.EmployeeID).OrderByDescending(p => p.Date).First(p => p.Date);
```